# mongoose findOne returning null after changing string key field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm using mongo db 2.6 and I have a users collection.
The users Schema has an "email" field which is the unique key for my records.
At some stage I have to change the key, so I do so, but it seems that after that a findOne with that new key fails:

```
var userObject = {"email" : "test123@gmail.com", ....}
var oldEmail = "tmp_email_123";

User.updateAsync({email: oldEmail},{$set : userObject))
.then (function( affected) {
    User.findOneAsync({ 'email' :  userObject.email}) <---- this returns null
})
```

However running against the db in the mongo console, shows the update was successful

```
db.users.find({"email":"test123@gmail.com"}) <---- returns the updated record.
```

Any clue why this might be happening?
I've been looking and deubgging this code for hours, with no clue.

Thanks!
D.

Comment: What are `updateAsync` and `findOneAsync`?

Comment: @JohnnyHK bluebird promise wrappers, however i debugged the mongoose code itself and got null..